# Autotabbing & Checking if variables is defined

Tags: qt, variables, tabs, defined

Well. Now again, i have some questions. Basically i'm doing two things. Autotabbing which is for example when you do if() you press enter and you go to next line, but you don't do the TABS to make it appear look like this:

```
if(a=1)
    //Basically, the line tabbed
```

And the system to check if a variable is defined. Like, you do:

```
QString Haha = "Haha";
Haha.blabla();
```

Well, basically when you don't define "QString Haha" the Haha.blabla wouldnt be colored. Any idea of how to check if X variable has been defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to do a fully featured code editor, you really need to implement parsing of the edited programming language. And that means a lot of work. For example, QtCreator does parse C++ and QtCreator's source code is available, so you could check from that how much work is required.

You can do a simple pattern matching syntax coloring using [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsyntaxhighlighter.html).

Answer (score 1):

About the autotabbing, you could try looking into [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent).

[Edit]
Removed the part about variable definition as I got your post wrong, sorry. 
The Syntax highlighter class linked by Roku will probably be for the best when it comes to syntax highlighting ;-)